# What is wrong with interpolation?

Tags: soft-question, interpolation

First of all interpolation definition is:

> interpolation is a type of estimation, a method of constructing
> (finding) new data points based on the range of a discrete set of
> known data points.

Over the course of my university years, I've been using interpolation, especially Lagrange interpolation polynomials a lot. But I cannot stop thinking that, isn't it somehow arbitrary? We go out and make a real-world observation, and when we somehow do not have enough data points, or we are missing some data points, we create new ones by means of some pre-defined deterministic algorithms. We take the past data points, multiply some data points together, add them up, and subtract them to have some new data. But once we've done it, aren't we solving another problem that has other parameters than the actual problem we had in the first place? The assumption here is that our observations are somewhat continuous and we can get really close to a data point simply by looking at the other points. Is that necessarily the case? I know things generally do not change abruptly but they do not have to be continuous also. Maybe you'll say that this is what we've got when we don't have enough observations.

Then the question becomes, aren't our interpolation techniques somewhat arbitrary? Can't I come up with another technique (simply take other data points, or make your polynomials higher degree) to make the new points? And is there any rigorous mathematical work to show how good these techniques are and how much closer can they get to real data points, how meaningful these calculations are?

Comment: Most techniques have empirical justification, whether or not they have a theoretical basis.  For example with polynomial methods, one issue is achieving the right balance between under- and over-fitting (you want to try to spot the pattern but ignore the noise); another is restricting their use to interpolation rather than extrapolation, which becomes difficult with high dimensions

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Realistically, this is why proper studies and experiments take as many data points as is possible, so values used can be purely from raw data rather than the interpolated. In order to validate raw data though repeats must be made and a lot of the time it is unfeasible to continue collecting data. In addition to this, most of the areas where interpolation is used are backed up by theory, with an equation that the curve should follow (also justifying a continuous function) and so it is reasonable to assume that between two points the data continuous to follow.

Comment: This strikes me as rather opinion based, the question itself, with little in the way of evidence to support it.

Comment: Do you want me to show you some examples where interpolation goes very wrong? You've already seen over fitting I guess @amWhy

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too vague. By definition, interpolation creates estimates for data you do not have. Which methods (if any) do that best depend on the problem. (Lagrange interpolation is often very poor - it leads to improbable oscillations.)

Comment: Question is perfectly valid ' is there any rigorous mathematical work to show how good these techniques are and how much closer can they get to real data points' @EthanBolker

Comment: If you don't know what the real data points are you can't know how close you are to them. There are lots of known results on the probable accuracy of various interpolation methods under various assumptions. Context is all.

Comment: If you choose an interpolation method arbitrarily, it will seem arbitrary.  Interpolation methods themselves are *not* arbitrary, though - they obey a set of rules, which work well in certain contexts and poorly in others.  Learning what assumptions a given interpolation scheme makes, and which situations satisfy or violate these assumptions, is much of the skill in using interpolation successfully.

Comment: @EthanBolker Take some number of experiments, delete some random data points, interpolate them and see how close you are?

Comment: That's a possible empirical approach, if you have a reliable data-generating process.  You'd probably want to use such a study to *verify* proved results about the accuracy of your interpolation from known properties of the system you're predicting, so that in the future you can possibly make informed predictions without actually running the empirical test.

Comment: So okay, it is better to not generalize and use a specific interpolation technique for a specific range of problems @user3716267

Comment: Yes; your interpolation technique *must* be appropriate for the system you're using it to describe.  The post below gives a good idea of what sort of assumptions the interpolation schemes are fundamentally making about the data source (namely, that it is "well-behaved" in some way, such as smoothness).

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what kind of data you are talking about, *but* if you are talking about real world data, or any other kind of data in which some kind of randomizing process is involved, then there's a lot of serious statistics involved in the kinds of questions you are raising. Are you interested in that statistical side of things?

Comment: I am talking about real-world data. And yes I am also interested in statistical side of it @LeeMosher

Comment: This problem reduces to statistics anyways

Comment: Okay, I agree. However, now there's an issue with your question: you don't even mention statistics, so it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation makes sense if you have reasons to assume that the functional that relates the data to the parameters has "sufficiently smooth" variations. The "knowledge" that the function is smooth is in itself some additional information that one has on the problem. E.g., interpolating the position of an object at some time point given its position at other time points can give good results if there is no "jitter" in the motion at a timescale shorter than the sampling.

Depending how regular (smooth), different interpolation techniques are more or less appropriate. The measurement noise is another aspect that sometimes needs to be taken into account.

In the absence of noise, for Lagrange, consider the [remainder formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Remainder_in_Lagrange_interpolation_formula): the bound is $\frac{(x_k-x_0)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\max_{x_0 \leq \xi \leq x_k} |f^{(k+1)}(\xi)|$, so it depends on the maximum absolute value of the $k+1$th order derivative: "sufficiently smooth" in this case means that the function should have its derivatives bounded by a constant up to that order. This is rarely the case in practice for large $k$, which means that the quality of Lagrange interpolation can then be poor.

Comment: Good one. It is very good for smooth motion but I remember I was doing this for some weather data (wind speed). And really any interpolation technique did not worth the effort.

Comment: For such data as with everything: if you have sufficient sampling, then interpolation can make sense. E.g., wind data every 15 minutes, if not in a storm, is probably good to interpolate if you want to know what thrust you should expect on a ship's sails. Interpolation, regression, ... all require an underlying model describing the functional and the measurements.